# What is the reason for the error message "System cannot find the path specified"?

Tags: cmd, directory, system32

I have folder `run` in folder `system32`. When I run `cmd` from within Total Commander opening a command prompt window with `C:\Users\admin` as current directory and want to go into that folder, the following error message is output:

> System cannot find the path specified.

When I open `cmd` directly in folder `run`, it works perfect. Why?

The command prompt window on opening in `C:\Windows\System32\run`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\run>cd..

C:\Windows\System32>cd run

C:\Windows\System32\run>
```

The command prompt window on simply running `cmd`:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Všetky práva vyhradené.

C:\Users\admin>cd..

C:\Users>cd..

C:\>cd windows

C:\Windows>cd system32

C:\Windows\System32>cd run
Systém nemôže nájst’ zadanú cestu.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is **not only 1** `%SystemRoot%\System32` on Windows x64. There are **2** such directories.

The real `%SystemRoot%\System32` directory is for 64-bit applications. This directory contains a 64-bit `cmd.exe`.

But there is also `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` for 32-bit applications. This directory is used if a 32-bit application accesses `%SystemRoot%\System32`. It contains a 32-bit `cmd.exe`.

32-bit applications can access `%SystemRoot%\System32` for 64-bit applications by using the alias `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative` in path.

For more details see the Microsoft documentation about [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector).

So the subdirectory `run` was created either in `%SystemRoot%\System32` for 64-bit applications and 32-bit `cmd` is run for which this directory does not exist because there is no subdirectory `run` in `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` which is `%SystemRoot%\System32` for 32-bit `cmd.exe` **or** the subdirectory `run` was created in `%SystemRoot%\System32` for 32-bit applications and 64-bit `cmd` is run for which this directory does not exist because there is no subdirectory `run` in `%SystemRoot%\System32` as this subdirectory exists only in `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64`.

The following code could be used at top of the batch file in case of subdirectory `run` is in `%SystemRoot%\System32` for 64-bit applications:

```
@echo off
set "SystemPath=%SystemRoot%\System32"
if not "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "" if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\* set "SystemPath=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative"
```

Every console application in `System32\run` directory must be executed with `%SystemPath%` in the batch file, for example `%SystemPath%\run\YourApp.exe`.

How it works?

There is no environment variable **ProgramFiles(x86)** on Windows x86 and therefore there is really only one `%SystemRoot%\System32` as defined at top.

But there is defined the environment variable **ProgramFiles(x86)** with a value on Windows x64. So it is additionally checked on Windows x64 if there are files in `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative`. In this case the batch file is processed currently by 32-bit `cmd.exe` and only in this case `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative` needs to be used at all. Otherwise `%SystemRoot%\System32` can be used also on Windows x64 as when the batch file is processed by 64-bit `cmd.exe`, this is the directory containing the 64-bit console applications (and the subdirectory `run`).

Note: `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative` is not a directory! It is not possible to `cd` to `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative` or use `if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative` or `if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\`. It is a special alias existing only for 32-bit executables and therefore it is necessary to check if one or more files exist on using this path by using `if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe` or more general `if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\*`.

Answer (score 29):

The following worked for me:

1. Open the `Registry Editor` (press windows key, type `regedit` and hit `Enter`) .
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` and clear the values.
3. Also check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to:

Step 1: Go home directory of C:\ with typing cd.. (2 times)

Step 2: It appears now `C:\>`

Step 3: Type `dir Windows\System32\run`

That's all, it shows complete files & folder details inside target folder.

[image]

Details: I used `Windows\System32\com` folder as example, you should type your own folder name etc. `Windows\System32\run`

Answer (score 0):

*create a folder in desktop
*open its properties and check the location path as below
[properties shows the location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhuVD.jpg)

we can find OneDrive(it can be something else in your pc) before the desktop
*Open cmd and run that before calling desktop
[Loading OneDrive Before desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He4Al.png)
*Than We can call desktop and create directory without error
[opening desktop and creating directory properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0GJ0.png)