# os.system("dir") not working after changing directory via os.chdir()

Tags: python, windows, shell, cmd, python-os

**Problem**

`os.system("dir")` not working after changing directory via `os.chdir()`

**Code**

```py
os.system("dir") # Works here
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir("..")
print(os.getcwd())
os.system("dir") # Does not works here
```

**Output**

```sh
C:\Folder1\Folder2
Volume in drive C is Windows_OS
Volume Serial Number is 0000-0000

Directory of C:\Folder1\Folder2

08/08/2019  12:14 PM    <DIR>          .
08/08/2019  12:14 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/08/2019  12:14 PM    <DIR>          Files.txt

C:\Folder1
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: this does not issue with python. check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638281/what-is-the-reason-for-the-error-message-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified

Comment: but that doesn't help my case. If the series of commands used above is done in cmd. Then, it executes all fine.

Comment: It only does not work if implemented in Python

Comment: Which Python version? Does `os.listdir(".")` work after `os.chdir("..")`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce that, it works as expected (Windows 7, Python 2.7). Do you have sufficient access privileges to the parent directory?