# Node's Npm module acting weird

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

The npm module when used via command prompt has suddenly started showing "The system cannot find the path specified". Problem is, when I reinstalled it, it still shows above error but also gives the result, the very next line.

```
C:\Users\******>npm -v
The system cannot find the path specified.
15.11.0

C:\Users\******>
```

I want to remove that irritating line, popping up every time I run a command!

Comment: It's unrelated to JavaScript, Node.js, or npm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638281/what-is-the-reason-for-the-error-message-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified